# Turning my own camera & record my self

Tags: c++, video, camera

I want to turn my own camera (that is connected to my computer already) and record my self for a few seconds and save it into any kind of file....

I searched the whole internet, and didnt found anything...

I'm using Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012, C++..

Thanks!

Comment: You've already "searched the whole internet"? Wow. The things we do for a few minutes of YouTube fame... :-)

Comment: Does this need to be within your application? There are ready-made command-line tools (such as `mencoder`) that can do this trivially.

Comment: Wow, the Internet changes so fast... Searching for "C++ webcam recording" on Google gives me a lot of helpful results...

Comment: I did search for it, but found nothing useful...

Answer (score 2):

There are opensource solution used for video security applications, you can use them to record your video also...

- http://www.ispyconnect.com/
- http://www.zoneminder.com

ispy is for windows (work on w7) and ZoneMinder is for linux just in case you need. As being opensource you can use them in your application also if needed.

Comment: I need to do it through C++...
For example, click run on the program, and my cam will turn on rigth away...

Comment: I beleive zoneminder is in C/C++, you can mold it as per your need, as its open source.